# How to package shared code for Ansible modules

Tags: python, ansible, setuptools

I had to write a few Ansible modules that all share code so I tried being clever and packaged them with setuptools.

[Here is the setup.py](https://gitlab.com/stemid/ansible-siptrack/blob/2eac2c59c9e3381c847827b4333d3ccf8e649c96/setup.py)

[Here is one of the modules](https://gitlab.com/stemid/ansible-siptrack/blob/2eac2c59c9e3381c847827b4333d3ccf8e649c96/siptrackmodulelib/siptrack_list.py)

The installed executable uses pkg_resources.load_entry_point and if I run it manually from CLI I can feed it JSON like this.

```
$ siptrack_list.py|jq
{"ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS": {"pattern": "vmlnx-web0"}}
{
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "pattern": "vmlnx-web0",
      "search_all": false,
      "max_results": 10,
      "regexp": false
    }
  },
  "output": [
    {
      "oid": "1238720",
      "name": "vmlnx-web02"
    },
    {
      "oid": "1238562",
      "name": "vmlnx-web01"
    },
    {
      "oid": "1771701",
      "name": "vmlnx-web03"
    }
  ],
  "changed": false,
  "returned": [
    {
      "oid": "1238720",
      "name": "vmlnx-web02"
    },
    {
      "oid": "1238562",
      "name": "vmlnx-web01"
    },
    {
      "oid": "1771701",
      "name": "vmlnx-web03"
    }
  ]
}
```

And it works! I get a result back in JSON.

But if I run it using the ansible or ansible-playbook executables I get this error.

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error: Module unable to decode valid JSON on stdin.  Unable to figure out what parameters were passed"}
```

Here is the playbook I use.

```
---

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: List siptrack devices
      siptrack_list:
        pattern: vmlnx-web02
        max_results: 1
      register: results

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ results }}"
```

So I'd love to find out what I'm missing here. Because I like using setuptools. The idea was to symlink the executables into an Ansible library dir. Or does anyone have another idea on how to share code between Ansible modules?

It also errors if I use ansible and call the module.

```
$ ansible -m siptrack_list -a 'pattern=vmlnx-we' -c local 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Error: Module unable to decode valid JSON on stdin.  Unable to figure out what parameters were passed"
}
```

Comment: Side note: `- debug: msg: "{{ results }}"` can be written as `- debug: var: results`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the confusing title I thought I'd post the true answer to this question. I was never able to use setuptools the way I wanted but I did find an official method of packaging shared code in ansible modules in the docs.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_module_utilities.html

This is even how Ansible themselves offer shared code common for openstack modules for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've not taken this approach before. What we did instead was to group libraries into logical groups and bundle them under Ansible role. The roles are published on internal GitHub, and referenced using Galaxy. The library will be made available to the entire playbook after "first run" of the role. So you just have to include the role before running any other task and the libraries will be available.

Comment: Ok could you clarify that? First of all I don't understand what a "logical group" is in this context. Secondly, it sounds like you're saying that a Python library bundled inside an Ansible role will be made available in PYTHONPATH to any playbook that uses the role, and thus any module used in said playbook will be able to import the library from the role? That sounds far fetched, why would a role affect PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I am merely saying that you may not want to include all your libraries into one role, but instead would rather divide them into several ones based on logical reasoning.

Comment: The role will be made available to the playbook only.

Comment: Ok now I think I understand, you mean that you put the python modules inside a library in the role, so the role alone can use the modules. Then you can use the modules from your play by including the role. I decided to go a simpler route and just make a library dir inside my git repo where I put both modules and shared code. So any user can just git clone the repo and add repo/library to their library path.